Text along curve or circle with Geometry Nodes
I'm trying to align text along a circle or curve using Geometry Nodes,

but it's very messy.

Where did I go wrong?
 (Blender v 4.1.0)

You can try this node setup:

But be aware that this does not take the right distance between the letters into account. But the rotation works.

Note: one thing is, the letters are not at position $(0,0,0)$, so if you translate them (which means: offsetting) the letters won't be on the points of the circle - as you have expected it. That's why I first do a set position to $(0,0,0)$ so that the instance on points does, what we expect it to do. The Align Euler to Vector node gives the instance the right rotation by using the curve tangent node.
You don't need a Sample Index node, because we plugin the rotation into the Instance on Points node, which "main" node tree is already the curve.

+1 ! it will look nice if you add a space after the last word in the String node! :D

@HarryMcKenzie: that's only a thing for a Pro like you are! ;)

i wish! haha XD
